# How to move Parse.com database to my own server and still use Parse.com SDK?

Tags: parse-platform, server

I'm using Parse.com SDK services for my Android app.

I've seen that Parse had released their Android SDK as an open source project on Github on [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android) address.

My app is almost finished, and when I'm uploading it to the Play Store, I don't want to be controlled by Parse.com (I mean that I don't want to be blocked someday, or I don't know that), so I want to move my whole database to my own server that hosted on a secure company.

I've checked the open source project on Github and realized that all I need to use it on my own server is to generate an Application ID and a client key.

So I want to ask if someone knows how to generate an Application ID and a client key of Parse to use it on my own server, or that you maybe knows another way of moving it to my server? And one more question: Today I'm using also Facebook SDK with my app. If I will move my database to my own server, will I still be able to use Facebook SDK on my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have write an article about how to migrate parse to a custom server.
https://medium.com/@jcminarro/run-parse-server-on-your-own-server-using-digitalocean-b2a7d66e1205

Comment: In addition to Jc's awesome article here is an article about adding push notifications to the server: http://www.tuogol.com/parse-server-android-push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

There's a ***massive*** difference between Parse open-sourcing their SDKs compared to revealing their entire backend architecture and its configuration.

The open-sourced SDKs are essentially wrappers for Parse's REST API along with some convenience functions and logic for natively interpreting the JSON data Parse is transmitting.

At a high level, Parse uses MongoDB for its core database and is entirely hosted using AWS (Amazon Web Services). The entire architecture is highly complex and is not something you could just drag and drop onto your own software stack or hardware backend.

To help give you a better idea of how Parse achieves all of their services, [here's an interesting presentation their Dev Ops team gave at an AWS convention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTjmG3b22I). Suffice it to say, hosting the backend services for over 180,000 apps requires a complex infrastructure and that is the "secret sauce" so to speak for Parse and is why Facebook purchased them for over $85 million two years ago.

Comment: Not. It would be much simpler to build out all of your own backend services on AWS than it would be to try to clone Parse but for only one app. For example you could use AWS S3 for storage needs and then access those resources using AWS API Gateway which will automatically create mobile platform SDKs for you to use.